# How to execute Maven's antrun between testCompile and test phases (before Surefire executes)?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

In my Maven build, I have a small block of Ant code that needs to run right before the Surefire kicks in to perform a few configurations.

The code is executed with antrun, but I can't get antrun to be executed right before Surefire.

Here is the relevant section of the output of my build:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com...tests ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\...\com...tests\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ com...tests ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\...\com...tests\target\surefire-reports
```

Basically I need antrun to execute between `maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile` and `maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test` .

I tried binding the antrun to the test phase and place it before the surefire plugin in the POM file, but it always executes after the Surefire plugin. I also tried to configure it to run in the testCompile phase, and place it after the maven-compiler-plugin plugin, but no success either.. it executes after surefire.

**Does anyone know how to get it to execute in between these two??**

Thank you!

Eduardo

Comment: What do you do via Ant which can't be done via Maven? Can you give us more details on that part?

Comment: In this case I'm updating a properties file. It could probably be done in Maven but the commands to update it come from a file containing 'sed' commands, so antrun seems the easiest way to read that file and get the sed commands executed before the tests run.

Comment: Why are you updating property file, cause you have a second set in `src/test/resources` for the test only without interfering the production property files in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: The properties file needs values that come from the build (and possibly Jenkins'parameters). It's not static, so I make the updates before running the tests. Thanks for pointing it out anyways :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute the antrun plugin in `process-test-classes` life-cycle phase which is just between `test-compile` and `test`

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look to the [build life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) you can see there are several steps between compile/testCompile and test...

```
compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy
```

So i would suggest to use `process-test-classes` in your case which is exactly the point you need.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! I was looking in another Maven help page where that phase was not listed! Thank you so much! (had to mark the other answer as correct as it came first, but upvoted yours)